# How can I exclude static directory in spring boot interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, static, interceptor

I tried like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry r) {
        r.addInterceptor(newInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
    }
}
```

But it didn't work and intercepted a /static/**  request

Comment: are you missing `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in the class?

Comment: @swapyonubuntu that will make things worse as that will disable Spring Boot autoconfiguration!.

Comment: @swapyonubuntu
As Deinum says, `@EnableWebMvc` mades things worse,,

Comment: other thing is I hope the package is being scanned in component scan